# How can I search several word in several fields at once?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search-engine, cakephp-2.3

I am coding a search module. I do not know if I am ina  good way but ti sound good for now excepted one point.

With the following code I can search only one word.

```
<?php
class SearchesController extends AppController{

    function index(){

        if($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post') ){
            // Save the send data
            $search = $this->request->data['Search']['key']; 

            //$nbWords = str_word_count($search);
            /*
            THIS DOES NOT WORKS
            if($nbWords > 1){
                $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

                $searchTermBits = array();
                foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
                    $term = trim($term);
                    if (!empty($term)) {
                        $searchTermBits[] = "Page.name LIKE '%$term%' AND Page.content LIKE '%$term%'";
                    }
                }



            }else{
                $term = $search;
                $searchTermBits[] = "Page.name LIKE '%$term%' AND Page.content LIKE '%$term%'";

            }
            */
            // SEARCH IN Pages TABLE
            $this->loadModel('Page');
            // SAVE THE RESULT IN
            $d['pages'] = $this->Page->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'online'=>'1',
                    'type'=>'page',
                    'created <= NOW()',
                    'id > 1',
                    'OR' => array(
                        //implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits)
                        'Page.name LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%',
                        'Page.content LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%'
                        )
                    ),
                'fields' => array('name','content','created','id','type')
            ));
            //SEARCH IN Posts TABLE
            $this->loadModel('Post');
            $d['posts'] = $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'online'=>'1',
                    'type'=>'post',
                    'created <= NOW()',
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Post.name LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%',
                        'Post.content LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%'
                        )
                    ),
                'fields'=> array('name','content','created','id','type','slug')
            ));
            // SEND THE VALUES TO THE VIEW
            $this->set($d);

        }else{
            echo 'e';
        }
    }

}
```

The problem, I would like to be able to search with different words, for exeple "red car", "house monrain","web html5 development"

With my code, if I enter one word, it return a result, but if I add second word to the first (with a space) , it retuirn no result.

How can I change this

```
'OR' => array(
        'Post.name LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%',
        'Post.content LIKE'=>'%'.$search.'%'
)
```

to make it able to search in 'name' and 'content' several words?

Thak for your help
Cheers

Comment: Tip: Don't reinvent the wheel - https://github.com/CakeDC/search Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
'OR' => array(
       'Post.name' IN ('name1', 'name2'),
       'Post.content' IN ('content1', 'content2')
)
```

Obviously you can put your value in array like this:

```
$name_arr = array();
$name_arr[] = 'name1';
$name_arr[] = 'name2';
```

and after:

```
'OR' => array(
           'Post.name' IN ($name_arr),
           'Post.content' IN ('content1', 'content2')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$search` variable

```
 $search = $this->request->data['Search']['key']; 
 // if keywords "red car" then it will pass to your query %red%car%;
 $search = str_replace(" ","%",$search);
```

Now it will search records having both words.

Comment: Houa Thank, I am going to try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with many words separated by a space, you can do this.

```
$searches = explode(" ", $search);
foreach ($searches as $search) {
   //put your search condition in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) searching. If you setup your indices correctly, you can run queries such as:

SELECT id, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial') FROM articles;